# trainings DependencyObject - custom command

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I try to create Command which inherit from DependencyObject and ICommand. I have the following code:

```
    public class CustomCommand : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AfterCommandProperty;
    static CustomCommand()
    {
        var ownerType = typeof(CustomCommand);
        CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(Action), ownerType, new PropertyMetadata(null));
        AfterCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AfterCommand", typeof(Action), ownerType, new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    public Action Command
    {
        get => (Action)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public Action AfterCommand
    {
        get => (Action)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Command & AfterCommand are always null
    }
}
```

and

```
    <Button Content="Test">
    <Button.Command>
        <command:CustomCommand  Command="{Binding Copy}" AfterCommand="{Binding AfterCopy}" />
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

When I press Test button **Command** and **AfterCommand** are null. Do you have an idea ? What is the best way cause I can't add ICommand reference to my ViewModel.

Thanks

Comment: Change to this: `Command="{Binding Copy, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` and see what you see in your debug output. I suspect you'll find that there's no context because it's not in the visual tree. You could try creating your command as a resource, and/or you could try various binding proxy strategies.

Comment: Incidentally, you've got a bug in the `AfterCommand` property: It's passing `CommandProperty` to GetValue/SetValue, not `AfterCommandProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CustomCommand instance isn't in the visual tree, so binding is a problem. It's got no way to get a DataContext. Try putting a trace on the binding:

```
<Button.Command>
    <local:CustomCommand
        Command="{Binding TestAction, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
        />
</Button.Command>
```

"Framework mentor not found" is the error you'll see in the debug output. "Ya can't get there from here" is how they'd say that Down East. Context in XAML is a matter of parent-to-parent, but this thing has, in the sense that matters here, no parent.

But it's an easy fix. Use a binding proxy. Here's a town bike implementation that I've stolen several times from [various questions and answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37854291/424129):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Define an instance as a resource in some containing scope that has the `DataContext` where the desired `Action` property lives. `{Binding}` with no path just returns `DataContext`, which will be the window's viewmodel in the case below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy
        x:Key="MainViewModelBindingProxy"
        Data="{Binding}"
        />
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it like so. The `Data` property of `BindingProxy` is bound to the viewmodel, so use a path of `Data.WhateverPropertyYouWant`. I called my `Action` property `TestAction`.

```
<Button
    Content="Custom Command Test"
    >
    <Button.Command>
        <local:CustomCommand
            Command="{Binding Data.TestAction, Source={StaticResource MainViewModelBindingProxy}}"
            />
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

### N.B.

You've also got a bug in your `AfterCommand` property: It's passing `CommandProperty` to GetValue/SetValue, not `AfterCommandProperty`.